# Access publicly available data from S3 bucket link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to access the data for reproducing the Redshift benchmarks on [this](https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/benchmark/) page. If you scroll down to **Run This Benchmark Yourself** section the author says the data can be accessed at the following S3 bucket replacing the items in `[]` with the format and data size that we are interested in:

```
s3n://big-data-benchmark/pavlo/[text|text-deflate|sequence|sequence-snappy]/[suffix]
```

Based on the above, I tried downloading the data using a link this way:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/big-data-benchmark/pavlo/text/tiny/
```

But it is not working. Can someone provide guidance on how to get these datasets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remove the "n" from `s3n://` I can list your directory:

```
    $ aws s3 ls s3://big-data-benchmark/pavlo/text/tiny/
    PRE crawl/
    PRE rankings/
    PRE uservisits/
    2013-05-03 10:13:42          0 crawl_$folder$
    2013-05-09 07:23:17          0 rankings_$folder$
    2013-05-09 07:22:36          0 uservisits_$folder$
```

from there I can get individual paths, e.g.

```
s3://big-data-benchmark/pavlo/text/tiny/crawl/part-00000
```

whose https URL would be:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/big-data-benchmark/pavlo/text/tiny/crawl/part-00000

Good luck!

Comment: Very helpful! Did not know there was a while aws CLI for s3. Wanted to say that I used the `sync` command to move the data to my bucket. This just made my day!

Comment: Useful! Thanks for that.